# How to do automatic user provisioning with AWS SSO with G-suite?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, synchronization, single-sign-on, google-workspace

I want to do automatic user provisioning for AWS SSO and G-Suite, for this, I am using [SSOSync](https://github.com/awslabs/ssosync). here when I'm going to use [AWS Serverless Application Repository](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home#/create/app?applicationId=arn:aws:serverlessrepo:eu-west-1:084703771460:applications/ssosync)   but it is showing the following error.

> You are not authorized to perform: serverlessrepo:GetApplication.

I gave full permissions to users but it seems like this application is not maintained longer. Do we have another alternative option for doing auto user provisioning?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://github.com/slashdevops/idp-scim-sync . The app you are requesting no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

AWS IAM Identity Center (AWS SSO) [supports now](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/06/aws-iam-identity-center-automated-user-provisioning-google-workspace/) automatic provisioning from Google Workspace.

See here how to enable it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/provision-automatically.html